# To display a Base64 image in AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs

I have inserted a Base64 image to a database using this Java code:

```
FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\basicsworkspace\\base64upload\\src\\main\\resources\\basic.png");
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = mFileInputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
    bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray();
//byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(ba); // Util
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(ba); // Apache
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
String insertSql = "INSERT INTO test (image) VALUES (?)" ;
prepsInsertProduct.setBytes(encoded);
System.out.println(insertSql);
prepsInsertProduct = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql);
System.out.println(prepsInsertProduct.execute());
```

But if I try to display the image in AngularJS using it, it is not displaying the image. In SQL Server I have saved my image as *varbinary(max)* and in AngularJS code,

```
config(function ($compileProvider) {
    console.log($compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist());
})

<img src="choice:image/png;base64,{{choice.Icon}}">
```

But I am getting only bytes with a message like this:

```
unsafe:choice:image/png;base64,6956424F5277304B47676F414141414E535568455567…
```

Where am I going wrong? The image is in PNG format.

Comment: Where is your JS that assigns the image to "choice.Icon"?  Your example looks as though you have HTML in your Javascript file.

Comment: Have you considered creating a separate HTTP request for the image on the server side, e.g. `http://server/img/345` and then insert the correct URL into HTML, e.g. `<img src="http://server/img/{{choice.IconID}}">`, instead of inserted the image data directly into HTML?

Comment: BTW: If you really use a data URI, it should be `data:image/png;base64,...` (not `choice:...`). And the data should be base 64 encoded; yours looks like a hex encoding.

Comment: I just need to store the data in base64 encoded , could you please advise how to keep base64 encode and get back, whereas I have tried to display some byte array code like this
<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="> and it works. I tried to insert byte array from Java as mentioned above and any idea on where I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In POJO I made changes for byte[] and it worked. I have datatype with String and modified to byte[] but Base64 images didn't displayed but t is displaying only byte array images.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your controller:

```
$scope.choice.Icon = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + yourImageData;
```

And in your HTML content:

```html
<img ng-src="{{choice.Icon}}">
```